# Samsung NP700G7C Screen Issue (data may be unplugged)

Tags: linux, display, xorg, slackware

I have a Samsung NP700G7C Laptop (c. 2009), still running reasonably fine but recently I dropped it (from a height of about 5cm) and since I get a blank screen. The screen is on but does not display anything. I have Slackware Linux on it. When I connect an external monitor, LILO comes up like normal and I can see the console and log in, but when starting X Server, I get an error that no screen is detected.
My suspicion is that the data cable got disconnected when I dropped it and this somehow prevents X from starting, but before I disassemble: Is my assumption correct or is it maybe a software issue after all and it just coincided with (or was otherwise caused by) the drop? Can I get an external monitor running on this laptop when its screen is disconnected? I tried to reconfigure X but when I try to start the server with the new conf file, it aborts with a segfault. I don't think it's a graphics card issue since I get "fb0: switching to nouveau" during system startup. How can I diagnose the problem and if the laptop screen is broken, get X to run with an external monitor?

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong subforum, I posted here since its a semi-hardware question.

Comment: I don't see how a drop can cause a software problem. Perhaps something has jarred loose, but only a visual inspection (and pushing everything into place) will tell.

Comment: by coincide I meant it could be a coincidence... probably yes, the screen has jarred loose, but why can't I just plug an external monitor?
I now tried to boot an Ubuntu and a Windows stick. Neither loads, but with the Ubuntu one I get a "GRUB _" on screen but no GRUB loading. I'm starting to wonder why the LILO and Slackware console don't malfunction when everything else does.

Comment: I can't answer that without physical access to the box.